# Configuring Gitlab review app

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to configure Gitlab review apps in my Ubuntu 14 server. First I want at least to makes work the example [explained here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/review-apps-nginx) also, installed gitlab runner, and configured one as said [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html)

I have a subdomain pointing to the IP of my server, let's say `mysubdomain.domain.com` I changed that in the nginx file.

Now, when I open `MymergeReq.mysubdomain.domain.com` nothing happens, I get: server not found.
If I open subdomain.domain.com I get the Nginx default index page.

My question is, where should I download that repo to make it work? I tried in `/usr/share/nginx/html` but the same, I think that I am missing some glue in all those things and I cannot find what is.

In the proposed Nginx file, in that tutorial, where they refer to the original place of the repo? or at least the  `.gitlab-ci.yml`  file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `MymergeReq.mysubdomain.domain.com` isn't working is due to the fact you have not set a wildcard DNS record for `*.mysubdomain.domain.com` is my guess.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should be that of your project.